# How to initialize a const char* ? and how to check if it exists or not?

Tags: c++11

I want to initialize a const char. It will be array of words.

```
const char **somechar;

//Is there any way to initialize here? //

value = somevalue;

somechar = new const char *[somevalue];

//After the use, How do I check if the array exists or not? (before deleting)

delete [] somechar;
```

Comment: Initialize and check for `nullptr`? Or just use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627776/how-to-initialize-char-in-c/71165594#71165594

Answer (score 0):

> How to initialize a const char* ?

Using any of default, value, copy or list initialization. However, note that default initializing a pointer leaves it with an indeterminate value and therefore not useful for anything except comparing with null, and assigning a new value.

> ```
> const char **somechar;
> ```

This default initializes `somechar` of type `const char **`.

> ```
> value = somevalue;
> ```

This has undefined behaviour, because `somevalue` was default initialized and therefore has an indeterminate value. Accessing an indeterminate value has UB.

> ```
> somechar = new const char *[somevalue];
> ```

This copy assigns `const char** somechar` and default initializes an array of `const char *` pointers.

---

> After the use, How do I check if the array exists or not? (before deleting)

You can only check whether a pointer is null, or whether two pointers point to the same object, or if the pointers point to the same array, you can compare their relevant order and distance.

If a pointer is null, it doesn't point to any object. If a pointer is not null, then it either points to an object that exists (the pointer hasn't been deleted) or it points to an object that has been destroyed and doesn't exist (the pointer has been deleted i.e. the pointer is dangling

There is no way to check whether a non null pointer points to an existing object or whether it is dangling. You must structure your program so that such check is not necessary. The simplest and popular way to achieve that is to wrap the arrays in a RAII container like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> somechar;
```