# How to initialize char ** in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm very new to C.

I'm supposed to do a simple wordsearch puzzle, so for the "dictionary" I did:

```
char **dictionary = {"DOG", "ELEPHANT", "CAT", "ETC", ""};
```

But when I try to compile, I get a warning saying 'excess elements in scalar initializer' for every word in the dictionary.
Is the char ** wrongly initialized? How should I do it?

EDIT: My functions recieve char **dictionary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `char **dictionary` or `char** dictionary`, not `char ** dictionary`.

Comment: it warns you correctly as it is pointer to pointer to char not pointer to array of char pointers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey why not? Elaborate.

Comment: @P__J__: Just have a quick look on the Internet for coding standards.  The vast majority of them have two rules; they are, in effect: 1.  Use `int *ptr`, and 2.  One declaration per line.  There is only one situation where space appears before ***and*** after the asterisk: `const int * const p1 = &something;`

Comment: @RobertHarvey ... please .... `static inline void dump_skb (char * prefix, unsigned int vc, struct sk_buff * skb) {`   - form the Linux  source. personal preferences. I use your "format" but other people prefer something else and I am not against

Answer (score 4):

```
const char *data[] = {"DOG", "ELEPHANT", "CAT", "ETC", ""};
const char **dictionary = data;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be useful to do that? If I must do the first line then I don't see the point in writing the second, since the static array has already been done. Also, I wouldn't be able to add/remove words, would I?

Comment: If you plan to iterate over the data, it is useful to be able to do `for( dictionary = data; ...; dictionary++)`

Comment: Why not just `char *dictionary[] = {"DOG", "ELEPHANT", "CAT", "ETC", ""};` ?

Comment: @Wyck but then I wouldn't be able to add/remove words, would I? I'm confused, not gonna lie

Comment: Yes, you can modify the array.  An array of pointers works like any other array.

Comment: @wyck Because an array of char * is not a char **, and the question is asking how to initialize the latter.

Comment: @Dan, it's not clear to me whether you are asking about your ability to "add/remove words" at _compile time_ or at _run time_.  Yes, you can modify the source code and the compiler will ensure that the `data` array contains enough storage (one pointer per string).  But no, you cannot add a 6th element to that array at run time because the compiler will only reserve memory for the 5 elements you initialized it with.  Assigning a value to `data[5]` is a _buffer-overrun error_. (remember indices start at 0, so if `data[0]` is the first element, then `data[5]` is the 6th element of in the array.)

Answer (score 1):

```
char **values = (char *[]){"a", "b", "c"};
```

or

```
const char *array[] = {
    "First entry",
    "Second entry",
    "Third entry",
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My doubt with that is, wouldn't I be wasting memory if I use char * array[ ] instead of a char **? Also, does this mean that I cannot initialize a char ** in any way?

Comment: How would you be wasting memory?

Comment: use `char *array[]` or `char* array[]`, not `char * array[]`.

Comment: @IgorRivin sorry, I messed up. I meant, I wouldn't be able to add o remove words, would I?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it is a personal preference. `char*p;` `char *p;` `char* p;` and `char * p;` are the same for the C compiler as it ignores white space.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
const char **addresses = {"0xabcdefgh"};
```

produces only a warning

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char **' with an expression of type 'char [11]'
[clang -Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and it fails when accessing `addresses[0]`.

Example:

```cpp
/*
clang t.c && ./a.out
gcc t.c && ./a.out
 */
#include <stdio.h>
void printaddress0(const char **addresses) {
    printf(addresses[0]);
}
int main() {
    //const char **addresses = {"0xabcdefgh"}; // segmentation fault
    const char *addresses[] = {"0xabcdefgh"};
    printaddress0(addresses);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//The best is to do like that
char **dictionary = new char*[] {(char*)"DOG", (char*)"ELEPHANT", (char*)"CAT", (char*)"ETC", (char*)""};

char* myword=new char[]{"my word"};
```